# Cuadrado formado por números y caracteres en C++

Tags: c++

Gracias a Candid Moe pude resolver mi duda con mi código pero ahora tengo otro problema un poco menos notable que es a partir en los digitos de dos cifras:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    int n;
    string sim;
    do {
        cin >> n;
        cin >> sim;
    } while (n<4 || n>22);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int j;    
    for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            cout <<"   "<< j + 1;
    }
    for (;j < n; j++) {
        if (j<10)
            cout <<"   "<< sim;
        if (j>9) 
            cout <<"     "<< sim;
    }
cout << endl;
}
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
   1   @   @   @   @   @   @   @   @   @     @     @
   1   2   @   @   @   @   @   @   @   @     @     @
   1   2   3   @   @   @   @   @   @   @     @     @
   1   2   3   4   @   @   @   @   @   @     @     @
   1   2   3   4   5   @   @   @   @   @     @     @
   1   2   3   4   5   6   @   @   @   @     @     @
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   @   @   @     @     @
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   @   @     @     @
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   @     @     @
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10    @     @
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10   11     @
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10   11    12
```

Pero sé que no se ve nada malo pero en los dígitos de dos cifras hay una diferencia (el símbolo debe estar a la altura del segundo digito )que hace que no sea igual al que me piden:

```
   1   @   @   @   @   @   @   @   @   @   @   @
   1   2   @   @   @   @   @   @   @   @   @   @
   1   2   3   @   @   @   @   @   @   @   @   @
   1   2   3   4   @   @   @   @   @   @   @   @
   1   2   3   4   5   @   @   @   @   @   @   @
   1   2   3   4   5   6   @   @   @   @   @   @
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   @   @   @   @   @
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   @   @   @   @
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   @   @   @
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10   @   @
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11   @
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
```

Podrían ayudarme  por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sólo te falta ajustar la impresión: en la fila n-esima, tienes que imprimir los n primeros enteros y luego el simbolo hasta completar el largo de la linea:

Quedaría asi:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int j;    // j recorre la fila
    //  Imprimir los enteros desde 1 a i
    for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
        cout << j + 1;
    }
    //  Imprimir el simbolo en lo que queda de la línea.
    for (;j < n; j++) {
        cout << sim;
    }
// Al final de cada linea, un '\n'
cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Se podría realizar de la siguiente manera:

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    char sim; // Lee un carácter, ya que asumo que solo leeras caracteres
    do 
    {
        cin >> n;
        cin.ignore(1, '\n'); // Ignora el salto de línea que se lee en: cin >> n;
        sim = getchar(); // Obtinene el carácter
    } while (n < 4 || n > 22);
    for (int i = 0; i < n ; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n ; ++j)
        {
            if (j <= i)
                cout << j + 1;
            else 
                cout << sim;

            putchar('\t'); // Imprime una tabulación para separar las columnas
        }
        putchar('\n'); // Otra forma de poner un salto de línea
    }
    return 0;
}
```